# Symfony2 form template bundle isolated

Tags: symfony, twig

So I have two bundles `AppBundle` and `AdminBundle` and I want to use a form template in each bundle, without calling `{% form_template ... %}` because I want to use it by default in every form.

I was using

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form:
        resources:
            - 'AppBundle::form_layout.html.twig'
            - 'AdminBundle::form_layout.html.twig'
```

The problem is that both templates are using in both bundles, they aren't isolated, I could create a new `FooBundle` and that bundle will use both templates... is there any way to set a specific template for a specific bundle(s) so they can be used by default?

Comment: It doesn't make sense until you have separate entry points and configs. That's because bundles aren't isolated in Symfony by design. They can cooperate and you can render multiple view from multiple bundles in one action.

Comment: I know they aren't isolated by design, if they were you couldn't cross entities between bundles (for example). I was thinking more about something that tells at twig level (maybe base theme?) that EVERY form, even if they are not called "form" to use an specific template, that would be awesome, some kind of "isolation".

Comment: A workaround could be to define template inline, but in layout file if you use separate layouts for these two bundles.

Comment: Layouts are independent, Admin has a total different than App. I think I will use `form_theme` everywhere..

Comment: That's the point. If they are different layout per bundle, you can define form theme in layout instead of in each template. But I'm not sure if you can do that actually :-)